# PyQT5 QFileDialog issues with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm using PyQt5 with Pycharm and Python 3.7 on Arch Linux (also tried with 3.8). When I run my code from PyCharm or directly from the command line the file dialog opens fine. However, when I build with **Pyinstaller** I get consistent errors when using them. Code:

```
def choose_log_location(self):
    self.log_location = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
        self,
        "Choose Log Files Directory",
        "/home",
        options=QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)

    if self.log_location != "":
        self.Log_Location.setText(self.log_location)
```

After building with Pyinstaller, running the built application and clicking the button that fires off this method I get 3 error dialogs pop up:

1. Error ?  URL cannot be listed file:///
2. Malformed URL
3. Error ?  URL cannot be listed file:///

Then, once the filedialog actually pops up, the main area is blank.

[image: Blank QFileDialog]

I also get the following error in the console:

> kf5.kio.core: ""
>   qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 7952,
>   resource id: 36398251, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0

I also get somewhat similar issues using QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() (blank area where files should be - note tested without filter, same result) but a different error in the console:

> kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found

[image: GetOpenFileName dialog]

Comment: Are you running the executable on Windows? Have you tried to set the path to a path that exists on your environment (or just an empty path)?

Comment: No, building and running on Linux. The workaround is to use the DontUseNativeDialog option as I found and a few others have done. However, it's a shame native versions don't function correctly.

Comment: Maybe PyInstaller changes something in the environment, making the dialog unable to show the contents. Do you confirm that it doesn't work even with an empty path? Have you tried the QUrl based statics (getExistingDirectoryUrl)? I found a [reference](https://www.mail-archive.com/pyinstaller@googlegroups.com/msg07822.html) in the pyinstaller mailing list: «Qt requires some other shared library to access the "Native File Dialogs"». But I believe that it could be related to QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME or XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP. Can you check the output of those vars when running from code and the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
It seems that pyinstaller produces this errors with native dialogs.
So my solution is to use the  `DontUseNativeDialog` option.

e.g.

```
self.log_location = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
        self,
        "Choose Log Files Directory",
        "/home",
        QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```